# preg_replace regex for (123):

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a preg_replace regex that will match and remove

```
(123):
```

and

```
(+12):
```

I've tried a few including

```
$str = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)/s', '', $str);
```

but none I've tried have removed the `()` brackets/parentheses nor the `+` sign

(yes I realise the `+` in the regex means plus/continue not an actual `+` sign) ;)

Comment: you should be more clear with your question...what pattern would the `()` contain..can they contain anything or only digits

Comment: I can't really see how i could make it clearer I have shown 2 clear examples of what I wanted matched/replaced first containing only numbers and the second + sign and numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the parenthesis and add the `+` sign to your character group:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\([+0-9]+\)/s', '', $str);
```

Comment: Or, do `/\(\+?[0-9]+\)/s'` depending on where he wants to allow the plus

Comment: @Jasper True, but that depends on the exact specifications.

Comment: agreed, I just added it because it's how I interpreted his question, but that doesn't mean your solution isn't correct

Comment: @AnnaRiekic: Sorry for calling you a him. Force of habit, I suppose.